# Calculating yearly forest gain from Hansen data set

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to calculate yearly forest gain in my specified area from the Hansen data set - I used the code given by google earth engine online and replaced the word 'loss' with 'gain' but it won't work saying 'gainyear' does not match any bands. How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var gainImage = gfc2014.select(['gain']);
var gainAreaImage = gainImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var gainYear = gfc2014.select(['gainyear']);
var gainByYear = gainAreaImage.addBands(gainYear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: tapajos,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(gainByYear);

var statsFormatted = ee.List(gainByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
print(statsDictionary);

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: statsDictionary.values(),
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: statsDictionary.keys()
}).setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Yearly Forest Gain',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '####'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area (square meters)'},
    legend: { position: "none" },
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3
  });
print(chart);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because there aren't any bands in `gfc2014` called "gainyear". Add a line after you create the `gfc2014` object with `print("gfc2014",gfc2014);` and you can see what bands are available; "lossyear" is in there but "gainyear" is not.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (based on sll28's comment below): You can't measure annual gain in the Hansen dataset! If you change "gainyear" to "lossyear" everything will run BUT it doesn't produce valid results. I am removing the code I had originally posted so nobody comes through and just copy-pastes it into EE expecting to get something useful.

Comment: thank you for your reply - it appears on greater inspection of the Hansen data set there is only data for 2000 and 2015 and no yearly data (unlike loss which has yearly data)